# How to resolve the Testserver problem in XUnit Test?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit, xunit.net

I am using xunit for testing my project. I was added all dependencies but i am getting following error.

```
The type or namespace name 'TestServer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

My test3.Tests.csproj dependencies

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

How can i resolve the problem.Any one try to help me thank you..

Comment: Did the package restore correctly? Your project targeting .net core 2.2?

Comment: go to command prompt console and make `dotnet restore` to install defined packages into your solution

Comment: ya it restored correctly. I am using the dotnet restore command.this is the out put : Restore completed in 71.87 ms for /home/ibrook/onlineconsultationdev/workspace/service/new/test3/test3.Tests/test3.Tests.csproj.
  Restore completed in 76.42 ms for /home/ibrook/onlineconsultationdev/workspace/service/new/test3/test3.csproj.

Comment: after the restore i am getting same error message

Comment: which namespace does the TestServer belongs to?

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost. In the namespace section also i am getting the error The type or namespace name 'TestHost' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing`.

> Infrastructure components, such as the test web host and in-memory test server (TestServer), are provided or managed by the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing package. Use of this package streamlines test creation and execution.

[Test app prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#test-app-prerequisites)